# Hash for guaranteed unique labels

Tags: node.js, hash, uniqueidentifier

I'm making labels for a set of objects, max of maybe 10,000.  The label format is `user-generated-name-h3b4`, with `h3b4` being the machine-generated hash.  How many chars do I need to guarantee uniqueness across the set of objects, and what hash function/library should I use?  (In either python or node.)

Comment: Does the hash need to be deterministic somehow?

Comment: It just needs to be guaranteed unique.

Comment: If you know the objects beforehand, then just keep track of the unique IDs you've generated so far, and if there's a collision, generate another?

Comment: I won’t have any tracking on them once generated. Looking for statistical unlikelihood. Trying to keep as short as possible, but wondering what the trade off would be, as in 4 char hash, 1 in X, etc. the consequences of a collision are not significant so I might go for shorter if it means the possibility of collision is there but relatively unlikely.

Comment: Right. Well, if they're randomly generated, there can never be a guarantee of no collision, the probability just decreases to "exceedingly unlikely" the longer the identifier and the larger its keyspace is.

Comment: Does the machine-generated hash have to be random-looking? Could the unique id generator just start at 0 and return the next sequential number each time? In general, the only way you can guarantee uniqueness is to keep track (explicitly or implicitly) of what's already been generated. For statistically unlikely, the chance of encountering a duplicate when generating 10,000 32-bit hash codes is something like 5%.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package for creating unique values https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqid

Also, this package is worth looking into
https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash